# String from service displayed UTF characters

Tags: android, web-services, utf-8

I received data from service:

Actually data in service: `Red Rock Casino • Resort • Spa`
But, when I tried to display in my class it displayed as: `Red Rock Casino â¢ Resort â¢ Spa`

how to displayed my data as same as service i.e want to displayed as: `Red Rock Casino • Resort • Spa`

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using below post:

[how/unable to convert garbled/strange text to utf-8 android (java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285775/how-unable-to-convert-garbled-strange-text-to-utf-8-android-java)

snippet:

```
String str = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
```