# how to add String in different language to paragraph of itext and make it visible properly?

Tags: java, itext

in My case,when i retrieve string of different language from database and add it to paragraph of itext.it is not displayed properly.
it is displayed as::

**???????????**

code as ::

```
Paragraph quetion_cell_paragraph= new Paragraph(100);
    String itemtext = new  String(multipleChoiceSingleCorrect.getItemText().getBytes(),"UTF-8");
                            quetion_cell_paragraph.add(itemtext);
```

please let me know the solution.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18286026/2398886

Comment: Are you sure the characters in question are supported by the font you use? Your code does not reflect any font setting at all, but the standard fonts are not overly complete concerning foreign characters.

Answer (score 0):

try adjusting 
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace (bottom left)
    // Text file encoding, chose Other, UTF-8.

Comment: Neither java nor iText inherently have a menu structure. The OP did not specify a special IDE or other GUI. So why are you trying to direct the OP to find some menu item?