# Confusion about Character encoding in HTML

Tags: html

How does a browser know what type of character encoding is used in a HTML page? I could specify, for example utf-8, in the html file, but how does a browser know it needs to use utf-8 before it reaches that string?

What if i specify utf-8 in the document but save the actual text file using a different encoding, what would the complications be?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order for UTF-8 to work, *everything has to be encoded for UTF-8*.  So if you import a text file that is encoded differently, the web browser will not change the file's encoding.  As a programmer, you'll have to either require that the uploaded file is encoded in UTF-8, or you'll have to convert the file's encoding to UTF-8.

Here are a few examples:

[UTF-8 text is garbled when form is posted as multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546365/utf-8-text-is-garbled-when-form-is-posted-as-multipart-form-data)

[how/unable to convert garbled/strange text to utf-8 android (java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285775/how-unable-to-convert-garbled-strange-text-to-utf-8-android-java)

[Garbled UTF-8 characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042950/garbled-utf-8-characters-in-php)

Lastly, I just came across this while searching for examples, this excellent article: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Thanks. Will check them out.